# In the formula $I = Q/t$, does $t$ always equal one?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, charge

From what I know, current equals the the number of charges passing through a certain point in a given amount of time (which I think is usually seconds?). Shouldn't $t$ always equal one (number of charges passing through a point in one second?) Why isn't current expressed as $I = Q$, then?

Comment: Because if $I=Q$, why would we need to define $I$ in the first place?

Comment: From what I know, the speed of my car equals the number of miles it travels during a given amount of time, which I think is usually in hours.   So if I wrote  Speed=$D/T$, shouldn't $T$ always equal one (number of miles driven in one hour?).   So why isn't speed expressed as Speed = $D$, then?  Why do we say that my car travels at a speed of 55 miles per hour when we could just say that it travels at a speed of 55 miles?

Answer (score 1):

This is an (ideal) **definition** of current, which you have used in your question.

For example, It's not the same thing as an experimental setup, which may not  be able to measure the quantities involved as easily as your question suggests.

Many physical terms are based around definitions, in which calculations invoving very small quantities are used, and then taken to the limit,  in other words: differential calculus.